# Custom background image

Tags: css, background

How to create background like this in css(middle and last block has fluid height):

[image: bg]

Are there any good tutorials?

Comment: Is it a background image you want to create in a graphics software or you want to use image(s) as backgrounds to get this effect in a layout?

Answer (score 4):

You would make the top and bottom `div` elements and set their css as follows:

```
#topBGDiv 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 125px; // Make this the height of the background image in pixels
    background-image: url('dark-gray-ribbon.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    overflow: hidden;
}


#bottomBGDiv 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px; // Make this the height of the background image in pixels
    background-image: url('light-gray-ribbon.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

use an image like this for the background image of the top:

[image]

and one like this for the bottom:

[image]

Lastly, set the CSS for the page's background-color to be the middle color.  So, something like this:

```
body
{
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
#top,#bottom
{
    height: 110px; // Make this the height of the background image in pixels
    background: url('BG.jpg') repeat-x left top;
}


#bottom
{
    background-position:left bottom;
}
```